# What's wrong with my method? Addition isn't working, always printing 0

Tags: java, hashmap

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    LinkedHashMap<String,Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(scan.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = line.split(" ");

        if(!Character.isDigit(tokens[0].charAt(0)) && !line.equals("clear") && !line.equals("var"))
        {
            int value = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<tokens.length; i++)
            {
                if(tokens[i].charAt(0) == '+')
                {
                    addition(tokens, value);
                    break;
                }

                else if(i==tokens.length-1)
                {
                    System.out.println("No operation");
                    break;
                }
            }
            map.put(tokens[0], value);
            System.out.println(map);
        }       

        if(line.equals("clear"))
        {
            clear(map);
        }
        if(line.equals("var"))
        {
            variableList(map);
        }       
    }
}

public static int addition(String[] a, int b)
{
    for(int j=0; j<a.length; j++)
    {
        if(Character.isDigit(a[j].charAt(0)))
        {
            int add = Integer.parseInt(a[j]);
            b = b + add;
        }   
    }
    return b;
}
```

I had this working all in the main method, but I wanted to separate it to make it cleaner. I must've done something wrong because now the addition method doesn't even function properly. For example, a = 5 + 6 should print the map {a=11}

Comment: What does your method do? Does it return something? Java is pass by value.

Comment: It's supposed to split a line into tokens, scan through the tokens to find what the sign is (+, -, /, *), then depending on the sign, it does that operation for the numbers. a = 5 + 6 would be split into 5 tokens, and when it finds +, it runs the addition method. The addition method should return b, which is value.

Comment: And what do you do with the returned value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
addition(tokens, value);
```

You're calling the method, but ignoring the return value. You should always be wary when you're calling a non-void method, but ignoring the return value. I suspect you want:

```
value = addition(tokens, value);
```

(There are various other stylistic changed I'd make - probably starting with changing the loop in `addition` to use an enhanced `for` loop: `for (String item : a)` etc. But this should at least get you started...)

Comment: How would you scan characters if I utilized the enhanced for loop?

Comment: @user2770254: The same way you do now - in your `addition` method you're just dealing with one string at a time, aren't you? Just change both occurrences of `a[j]` with `item`...